# SVN hook for copying committed files and folders?

Tags: svn, copy, hook

I have a SVN repository running on my Windows 2008 server. It has 2 apps in it right now, lets call them App1 and App2. I want to copy the committed files for the apps to another place on the server, one for each app. I want to do that after the commit, so I think the post-commit hook is the one to use?

How do I know which app got new files and how would the copy command look? Files for App1 have to go to c:\app1 for example, files for App2 to c:\app2.

Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to have a checked out working copy of your repository on the server in some path and in the `post-commit` as you rightly mentioned, just do an `svn update` on the checked out working copy.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like it could work. Can you post the content of the post-commit.bat file please?

Comment: To what path? The path of the checked out app1 for example? How do I know the path? Is that $1?

Comment: @EOB - it has to be a pre-determined path. You are checking out a working copy. Say to c:\workingcopy\projectA. cd to that and svn update.

Comment: Yeah, but still, in the hook file I need to dynamically figure out which path? No? I mean, my repository has one hook file, but 2 (or more) apps. Sp I checkout every app to c:\app1, c:\app2 and so on. So I need to "cd app1" or app2, whatever is coming ... or dont I get what you mean?

Comment: @EOB - Why are you checking out app by app? Check out the entire repo. That will keep it simple. Otherwise you will have to use an util called `svnlook`, see the paths changed, figure out which app, update that and so on.

Comment: But you said: *@EOB - it has to be a pre-determined path. You are checking out a working copy. Say to c:\workingcopy\projectA. cd to that and svn update.* Do you mean to cd to EVERY app, one after each other and run svn update?

Comment: Works exactly as u said! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

post-commit is indeed the one to use.

If we look at the example for svnnotify..

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

/usr/local/bin/svnnotify                    \
    --repos-path    "$REPOS"                \
    --revision      "$REV"                  \
    --subject-cx                            \
    --with-diff                             \
    --handler       HTML::ColorDiff         \
    --to            <your e-mail address>   \
    --from          <from e-mail address>
```

Looks like $1 is the repo-path and $2 is the rev.. So you should be able to just do a regex against $1 to test if it's in one of the two paths you're interested in and take action accordingly (or, not)

Culled from: [Subversion Post-Commit Hooks 101](https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101)

Comment: Can you tell me how the regex stuff would look like iyo?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir='/path/to/something/special'
dir='/path/to/other/thing'


if [[ $dir =~ "something" ]]; then
    echo "something dir"
fi

if [[ $dir =~ "other" ]]; then
    echo "other dir"
fi
```

Comment: cygwin? Otherwise - grab a powershell manual and start readin. :p